# PostgreSQL Select Query for Date

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp

I have a table in Postgres database "logs" which holds the error logs with their creation date

sample query  : `Select creation_date from logs`

returns

```
"2011-09-20 11:27:34.836"
"2011-09-20 11:27:49.799"
"2011-09-20 11:28:04.799"
"2011-09-20 11:28:19.802"
```

I can find out the latest error using the command

```
SELECT max(creation_date) from log;
```

which will return "2012-02-06 12:19:28.448"

Now what I am looking for a query which could return the errors occured in last 15 minutes.

Any help on this will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM logs WHERE creation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL '15 minutes'
```